# Nunit 3.0 Beta 4; Test Cases are not being discovered using TestCaseSource

Tags: c#, excel, nunit, nunit-3.0

I've a project where I'm reading a excel file for the test cases.The code for reading the excel and mapping the cases to C# classes is being done like this

```
class AllTests{
 public static IEnumerable DemoCases
        {
            get
            {
             //Read the excel map the cases here
             yield return testcasedataObject;
            }
        }
    }
```

And the test method looks like this

```
 [Test, TestCaseSource(typeof(AllTests), "DemoCases")]
        public void DemoTest( )
        {
          //Test execution code
        }
```

Now all this works fine with Nunit 2.6.4, but with the beta the excel is not being read while discovering test cases. I need to use the TestFixtureSource of the beta alongwith the TestCaseSource.

Comment: That's right, I'm facing the same issue on NUnit 3.2.1. Haven't been able to find any bug report about this. Any idea?